# Wrapped types like in F#

Tags: typescript

In F# I can wrap a primitive type like `string` that way:

```
type CustomerId = CustomerId of string
let id: CustomerId = CustomerId("123")
```

If I'm using an `int` instead of `CustomerId("123")` like this:

```
let id: CustomerId = 123
```

I get this error:

```
This expression was expected to have type
    'CustomerId'
but here has type
    'int'
```

Now I'm trying to do something similar in TypeScript that way:

```
type CustomerId = string
const id: CustomerId = '123'
```

First, I can not assign `CustomerId('123')` to `id` and second if I'm assigning a `number` instead of a `string` to `id`, TypeScript just gives me this error:

```
Type '123' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Whats the closest (without using classes and interfaces) I can get using TypeScript compared to the F# implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get pretty close using the following:

```
type CustomerId = { CustomerId: string}
```

In TS we can't do the equivalent of constructing a case by just wrapping a primitive value with a `CustomerId` but you can create a simple helper method that does it for you:

```
const customerId = (id: string): CustomerId => ({ CustomerId: id })

const a = customerId("123")
// a = CustomerId
```

And TS will give you type errors if you use the wrong type in the constructor

```
const a = customerId(7)
//                   ^
// Argument of type '7' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'
```

Comment: The downside of this solution is, `console.log(a)` will result in `{ customerId: 7 }`